# show custom dialog on menuitemtemplate click

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have to open a custom dialog box on click of menuitemtemplate.

I tried:

```
menuitemtemplate.ClientOnClickNavigateUrl ="javascript:sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog({url:'http:/sharedev/sitecreate.aspx'width:200px })"
```

But it shows only as a simple page, not as a popup dialog.

What should I do?

Comment: when you say it shows as a simple page you mean it is basically redirecting the browser to that page ?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is case sensitive, and you're also missing a comma in the options. This should work better:

```
menuitemtemplate.ClientOnClickNavigateUrl ="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:'http:/sharedev/sitecreate.aspx', width:200px });";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **ClientOnClickScript** property instead of ClientOnClickNavigateUrl

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use :

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate ID="MenuItem_OpenPopUpPage" runat="server" Sequence="1"
 Text="Open Modal Dialog"
 ClientOnClickScript="OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('/SitePages/Page.aspx', RefreshOnDialogClose, null, null,'PopUp Title')" />
```